# Calculate the first N terms of a geometric sequence in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sequence

How to calculate the first N terms of the geometric sequence Un = 2^n in Matlab?

Are there any Matlab functions that I'm not aware of to facilitate this? or do I have to pick a math book to understand this and implement it in a for loop or something?

Any links to similar Matlab code would be appreciated, or if you could explain it for me that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, you set the N terms for your sequence, i.e.:
    N = 10 %//set first 10

Now you want to make a vector from 1 to N, i.e.:

```
n= [1:N]
Un = 2.^n %//Note the dot is very important! I almost forgot
%//ans = [2,4,8,16...1024]
```

This would make function a vector of 1 by N where each element is the corresponding answer to your function.

for your second question (in comment)

you want to do something like:

```
Bflip = B' %//This flips the matrix B so that what use to be column is now rows
```

So Bflip would be the result you want, I tested with your example:

```
A = [2 2 2;4 4 4; 6 6 6];
B = [0 0 0; 1 1 1; 2 2 2];
Bflit = [     0     1     2
              0     1     2
              0     1     2]
```

This will generate a 3 dimension matrix. To call on each of the 4 sets of results, just do something like result1 = permutation(:,:,1)

Comment: This seems to be what I was after, thank you.

Comment: A different question you may have an answer to is, if I have two matrices (4x4) and I want to permute the lines of A with columns of B. How do I go about that? Thanks you a lot!

Comment: hmm, so you want to do each row of A P (stands for permutation) each column of B?

Comment: yes, each row of A with each column of B.

Comment: just to make sure I am correct, say A(:,1) = [1,2,3,4] B(1,:) = (5,6,7,8), you want your result to be a matrix of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7 etc i.e. 8! number of rows in your matrix?

Comment: A = [2 2 2;4 4 4; 6 6 6] and B=[0 0 0; 1 1 1; 2 2 2]. I want A to become A[0 1 2; 0 1 2; 0 1 2] (i.e. the columns of B become the row of A). Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have now updated the post to answer your second bit of question